# Different data types in java

Tags: java, object, reflection, field

I am using reflection to extract the field type from Java objects at runtime. These fields are being categorized as:

- Primitive Type
- Fields having package name starting with Java.lang.*
- Fields having package name starting with Java.util.*
- Array types

For Custom Objects(User defined) in the field: These are again explored for their fields and their respective fields categorized.(Recursive call)

I wanted to know whether the above categorization will be enough for any object or some extra categories are required for more meaningful categorization.

Comment: It's unclear what you consider "meaningful categorization".

Comment: By meaningful categorization, I mean whether above categorization will be able to handle any generic object. Actually, after categorizing I am trying to get the field value. So when I see a primitive type I can get its value, or a java.util.* type then I am sure that it must be a list, map(values can be accessed using iterators) or other types like Calendar, Date(values can be accessed via toString()). Same is the case with java.lang.* and Array type. So whether these categories will be enough for accessing the values set by a user for that object?

Comment: What about custom types from another package?

Comment: I suppose here by custom type you mean user defined type. If that is the case then it will be treated as a custom object and a recursive call(now with this custom object as parameter) will categorize it into the given categories

Comment: So you're basically ignoring fields of custom types? I'm still not clear on what the goal is here.

Comment: Let's take an example: Class A{int, String, B}  Class B{int, String}. So when an object of Class A is passed to the function, its field will be explored via reflection. int-->primitve type, String will be ----> java.lang.* type and B will be ----> custom type(for which again the function will be called and the same thing repeated). So finally by passing an object A: the field values explored are: int and string of class A object & int and string of class B object(which was present as a field in class A)

Comment: Ok, I understood as much. But what's the purpose of this classification? And what is your question exactly?

Comment: The purpose is to extract the values that had been assigned by the user to different  fields of the object, therefore the question was to know whether my classification will work for every type of object

Answer (score 0):

I do stuff like this for debugging and I just check for `Iterable` and sometimes `Map`. Trying to account for every possible type statically is a bit of a fool's errand. If you want to handle any possible type, a good idea is to just create a simple way to register a converter function. Then clients of the API can do essentially whatever they want.

Here's a relatively quick example:

```
package mcve.reflect;

import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public interface DebugReadout {
    /**
     * Prints a readout of all instance fields in {@code this} to the
     * specified print stream.
     * 
     * @param   out 
     * @throws  NullPointerException
     */
    default void readout(PrintStream out) {
        Class<?> clazz = getClass();
        out.printf("%s {%n", clazz.getSimpleName());
        do {
            for (Field f : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
                if (!Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers())) {
                    String value;
                    try {
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        value = Details.toString(f.get(this));
                    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException
                           | SecurityException x) {
                        value = "UNAVAILABLE";
                    }
                    out.printf("    %s = %s%n", f.getName(), value);
                }
            }
        } while((clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) != Object.class);
        out.printf("}%n");
    }
    /**
     * Registers a converter function.
     * 
     * @param   <T>
     * @param   type
     * @param   fn 
     * @throws  NullPointerException
     */
    static <T> void put(Class<T> type, Function<? super T, String> fn) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        Objects.requireNonNull(fn);
        Details.CONVERTERS.put(type, fn);
    }
    /**
     * Returns a converter function or {@code null} if one didn't exist.
     * 
     * @param   <T>
     * @param   type
     * @return  a converter function
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> Function<? super T, String> get(Class<T> type) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(type);
        synchronized (Details.CONVERTERS) {
            Function<?, String> fn = Details.CONVERTERS.get(type);
            if (fn == null) {
                for (Class<?> key : Details.CONVERTERS.keySet()) {
                    if (key.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                        fn = Details.CONVERTERS.get(key);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (Function<? super T, String>) fn;
        }
    }
}

class Details {
    static final Map<Class<?>, Function<?, String>> CONVERTERS =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    static <T> String toString(T obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return "null";
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Function<? super T, String> fn =
            (Function<? super T, String>)
                DebugReadout.get(obj.getClass());
        if (fn != null) {
            return fn.apply(obj);
        }
        if (obj.getClass().isArray()) {
            return IntStream.range(0, Array.getLength(obj))
                            .mapToObj(i -> toString(Array.get(obj, i)))
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
        }
        if (obj instanceof Iterable<?>) {
            return StreamSupport.stream(((Iterable<?>) obj).spliterator(), false)
                                .map(e -> toString(e))
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
        }
        if (obj instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            return toString(((Map<?, ?>) obj).entrySet());
        }
        return obj.toString();
    }
}
```

A more robust routine would keep an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) of every object seen so far (perhaps excluding known value types like `String` and `Integer`) so you don't end up with infinite recursion in a case where two objects reference each other.